# CSS nowrap & wrap combination miscalculates child width

Tags: html, css

I want to place icon and text next to each other vertically centered. Icon is in sprite so I cannot use centered background image because of the need to clip it.

[image: text spilling outside of intended area]

It works when I hack the text content with right padding of the same saze the icon has, however it seems like a bug to me that it fails to calculate the width correctly.

[image: corrected with a padding hack]

HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td class="col0">
        <a href="javascript:alert('click')">
            <span class="icon"></span><span class="text">a name that is so long that it needs multiple lines to be displayed, lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, blablablabla, sdfsfsdfgsdfgsdfsafd</span>
        </a>
    </td>
    <td class="col1">some value</td>
</tr>
```

CSS:

```
.col0 span {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}
.col0 .icon {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/tyte2jp.png);
    background-position: -229px -39px;
    margin-right: 4px;
}
.col0 .text {
    white-space: normal;
    text-decoration: inherit;
    /*margin-right: 24px;*/
}
```

[whole example on codepen](http://codepen.io/mzknksh/pen/WQXqRm)

---

Just realized we could hack this away with negative margin on the icon and get rid of the ugly nowrapping. However I was wondering why the blocks do not calculate their widths correctly when nowrap is on.

Comment: Do not update your codepen after you posted it, otherwise no one will be able to see what you're really talking about in the question.

Comment: sorry, guess I'm used to jsbin versioning, I'll change it back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was wondering why the blocks do not calculate their widths correctly

The width is calculated according to the spec. For [inline-block, non-replaced elements in normal flow](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#inlineblock-width), `width: auto` is calculated using the [shrink-to-fit](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#shrink-to-fit-float) algorithm:

> Calculation of the shrink-to-fit width is similar to calculating the
>   width of a table cell using the automatic table layout algorithm.
>   Roughly:
>
> 1. Calculate the preferred width by formatting the content without breaking lines other than where explicit line breaks occur
> 2. Also calculate the preferred minimum width, e.g., by trying all possible line breaks. CSS 2.1 does not define the exact algorithm.
> 3. Find the available width: in this case, this is the width of the containing block minus the used values of 'margin-left',
>      'border-left-width', 'padding-left', 'padding-right',
>      'border-right-width', 'margin-right', and the widths of any relevant
>      scroll bars.
>
> Then the shrink-to-fit width is: min(max(preferred minimum width,
>   available width), preferred width).

Therefore, the available width only considers the content width of the containing block, without subtracting the width of other elements.

If you don't have to support old browsers, I suggest using flexbox instead:

```css
.col0 > a {
  display: flex; /* Single-line row magical layout */
  align-items: center; /* Center items vertically */
}
.col0 .icon {
  flex-shrink: 0; /* Do not shrink this item in case there isn't enough space */
}
```

```css
td {
  border: solid 1px;
}
.col0 {
  width: 20em;
}
.col1 {
  width: 5em;
}
.col0 > a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.col0 .icon {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/tyte2jp.png);
  background-position: -229px -39px;
  margin-right: 4px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="col0">
      <a href="javascript:alert('click')">
        <span class="icon"></span>
        <span class="text">a name that is so long that it needs multiple lines to be displayed, lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, blablablabla, sdfsfsdfgsdfgsdfsafd</span>
      </a>
    </td>
    <td class="col1">some value</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: nice one, still the compatibility is worse than calc() :(

Comment: With this solution the icon is cutted. I love flexbox, but for this purpose I think that's exagerated.

Comment: It doesn't matter, The box that contains the icon is less than 24px width (exactly 22.05 pixels), because flexbox is trying to reduce the width to make the calculations. Check it ;) In my solution the box is exactly 24px width and it fits perfectly

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude OK you are right, I forgot `flex-shrink: 0`

Comment: Yeah, now it's perfect!

Answer (score 1):

You aren't defined the width, so all `<span>` will take 100% of the width. If your icon has 24px width, you can make this:

```
 .col0 span.text {
      width: calc(100% - 24px);
 }
```

This makes a calculation of the 100% of the TD and then substracts 24 pixels of the icon width.
See it working:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LpOKvd

See compatibility of `calc()`  function:

http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

Comment: a colleague found that one but we are not sure if we could get this greenlighted due to compatibility

Comment: What browsers you need to render it? Your problem is the table, that is better with <div> than the <table> and <td>

Comment: At least IE9, not sure if the support for IE8 is already dropped completely with our product though. The table is a requirement (the context is this is part of table with component names and states and associated values, the example is simplified to illustrate the issue at hand)

Comment: If you use `white-space: nowrap` your only solutions are making good calculations. With calc function the calculation is perfect. Without it you need to put a padding or a margin, or define the correct width to the two elements (icon 24px and text 100%-24px)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a bit of a misuse of the `white-space` property. I'm not surprised you're running into difficulty with it. Perhaps its better to avoid it and put the `icon` inside the `a` instead?

http://codepen.io/moob/pen/pjdMLw

```css
td {
  border: solid 1px;
}
.col0 {
  width: 20em;
  position:relative;
}
.col0 a {
  display:block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-decoration: inherit;
  margin-left: 32px;
}
.col0 .icon {
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:4px;
  bottom:0;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  margin:auto;
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/tyte2jp.png);
  background-position: -229px -39px;
}
.col1 {
  width: 5em;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="col0">
      <a href="javascript:alert('click')">
        <span class="icon"></span>a name that is so long that it needs multiple lines to be displayed, lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, blablablabla, sdfsfsdfgsdfgsdfsafd
      </a>
    </td>
    <td class="col1">
      some value
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: ha, I was completely oblivious to the possibility of setting both opposing coordinates for absolute positioned element at the same time. interesting.